# Playing music from the computer on a iPhone Bluetooth Headset

Tags: macos, iphone, bluetooth, headset

I'd like to use the "iPhone Bluetooth Headset" headseto play
music from my OS X laptop. I can pair my laptop and the
headset without any problems, but setting the sound
output device to the headset unfortunately doesn't produce
any sound.

The problem is of course due to the fact that the headset
doesn't support a2dp, but is there a hack/third party
program I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> headset doesn't support a2dp

AFAIK, no. Without A2DP it is not possible

Comment: It is possible though to write a driver using a different protocol.
But has anyone actually done that?

Comment: Can't find something for OS X. Found a softy for WInMo, however

Comment: Can you remember where?

Comment: Here you go - http://www.davidmays.com/BTAudio/ Please do note, as I mentioned above, its for WinMo