# Sending output to both bluetooth headset and normal speakers - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, speakers, headset, audio

Hey, I have a bluetooth "headset" (it's more like a speaker with a microphone on it, but it registers as a headset) and I want to play music through it. I also want to play the same music through the "normal" speakers on the laptop. Is this possible?

If so, is it possible to play two *different* streams on each speaker? Say if I wanted to DJ a party or something, I'd want to hear the upcoming song and mix it before sending it live.

Comment: On point #1: http://superuser.com/questions/27878/playing-music-from-the-computer-on-a-iphone-bluetooth-headset

Answer (score 0):

> "headset" (it's more like a speaker with a microphone on it, but
>   it registers as a headset) and I want
>   to play music through it.to play music through it.

I'm guessing the headset doesn't support A2DP profile ?
In this case,its not possible to play music on your headset.

> is it possible to play two different
>   streams on each speaker? Say if I
>   wanted to DJ a party or something, I'd
>   want to hear the upcoming song and mix
>   it before sending it live.it before sending it live.

I'm not completely certain but I don't think this is possible either. I have a stereo  bluetooth headset, and the sound is always redirected to one source, either the headset or the laptop speakers, never both.

Comment: No, I can play music on it currently, but I want to be able to play it on the headset *and* the normal speakers at the same time.